# Clickonce does not run

Tags: installation, clickonce, web-deployment

I have found several forum posts about "clickonce does not run/start/install" but none is like my problem.

I'm using ClickOnce for several projects and they work fine. I'm trying to install on a pc but for an unknown reason : nothing. I mean, I launch the "setup.exe" (using firefox), it opens Internet Explorer with the link of the .application file (it's deployed on the web), then IE closes and nothing else.

I tried on two others computer and the setup.exe launchs the installation of the application.

I tried to reinstall the .Net Framework but same thing happens, I disabled Avast and the Firewall, same thing.

How can I fix this, or fins out why it is happening?

Comment: This could be a problem with the specific PC, or with the IE installation or settings, or pretty much anything. If you really need to get your app installed on it you can always copy it locally and install it.

Comment: yes that's why i do :) thanks

Comment: @stuartd i just test to install using the setup on a local folder, it launches nothing. i test on an other pc, it works perfectly, i understand nothing lol

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before:

Delete/rename C:/Documents and Settings/(User)/Local Settings/Application Data/Microsoft/Windows/UsrClass.dat file (=HKEY_USERSUserSID_Classes=HKCUSoftwareClasses in registry) while the user is logged off and let it recreated automatically when the user log on next time.  This is to clean up the access right to the registry.